# Link SQS event trigger between serverless and localstack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, localstack

I have SNS, SQS, and many services created in localstack (docker). I use serverless framework for Lambda functions and API endpoints.

I would like a lambda function (serverless framework) to be triggered when there is a message in a Queue but SQS is created in localstack. Is this possible?

Comment: It depends - how are you running your Lambda locally? Within LocalStack? Or are you using `invoke —local` for your Lambda and then your SQS queue is in LocalStack?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary running lambda from serverless framework locally. `invoke —local` for my lambda and SQS queue is in LocalStack